# Why is my I2C function inverting bytes?

Tags: sensor, i2c, msp430

I'm working with a MSP430G2553 and a BMP180 sensor. I have the following function in my program

```
uint16_t leer_temp_des() {
    unsigned char temp[2];
    escribir_com_bmp180(CTRL_MEAS, LEER_TEMP);
    retardo_ms(RET_LEC_TEMP);
    leer_2_bytes_bmp180(OUT_MSB, temp);
    printf("t0 %u\n", (uint16_t) temp[0]);
    printf("t1 %u\n", (uint16_t) temp[1]);
    uint16_t temperatura = ((uint16_t) (temp[0] << 8) | (uint16_t) temp[1]);
    printf("t %u\n", temperatura);
    //temperatura <<= 8;
    //temperatura |= temp[1];
    return temperatura;
}
```

Which calls this other function

```
void leer_2_bytes_bmp180(uint8_t reg, uint8_t *v) {
    inicioI2C(DIR_I2C_BMP180);
    envioI2C(reg);
    reinicioI2C(DIR_I2C_BMP180, false);
    *v = recepcionI2C(false);
    *(v + 1) = recepcionI2C(false);
    finI2C();
}
```

I2C code

```
void inicializarI2C() {
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
    UCB0CTL0 &= ~(UCA10 | UCSLA10 | UCMM);
    UCB0CTL0 |= (UCMST | UCMODE1 | UCMODE0 | UCSYNC);
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSSEL1 | UCSSEL0;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    UCB0STAT = 0;
    UCB0BR0 = 160;
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0I2COA = 0x1A;
    UCB0I2CSA = 0x77;
    P1DIR |= BIT6;
    P1SEL |= BIT6;
    P1SEL2 |= BIT6;
    P1SEL |= BIT7;
    P1SEL2 |= BIT7;
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
}

void inicioI2C(uint8_t dir) {
    UCB0I2CSA = dir;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    while((IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) == 0) {}

    //while((UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) == 0) {}
}

void reinicioI2C(uint8_t dir, bool rw) {
    UCB0I2CSA = dir;
    if(rw) {
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    }
    else {
        UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;
    }
    //UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT) != 0) {
        if((UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) != 0) {
            break;
            /*UCB0STAT &= ~UCNACKIFG;
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
            while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP) != 0) {}*/
        }
    }
}

uint8_t envioI2C(uint8_t dato) {
    //UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    //UCB0I2CSA = dir;
    //UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    UCB0TXBUF = dato;
    while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT) != 0) {}
    if((UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) != 0) {
        UCB0STAT &= ~UCNACKIFG;
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
        //while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP) != 0);
        return 0;
    }
    while((IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) == 0);
    return 1;
    //retardo_ms(1);
}

uint8_t recepcionI2C(bool parar) {
    //UCB0CTL1 =& ~UCTR;
    //UCB0I2CSA = dir;
    //UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    if(parar) {
        if((UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) != 0) {
            UCB0STAT &= ~UCNACKIFG;
        }
        UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
    }
    while(!(IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG));
    uint8_t dato = UCB0RXBUF;
    //while(!(IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG));
    if(parar) {
        while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP) != 0) {}
    }
    return dato;
}

void finI2C() {
    if((UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) != 0) {
        UCB0STAT &= ~UCNACKIFG;
    }
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
    while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP) != 0) {}
}
```

Obviously, temp[0] is supposed to store the most significant byte while temp[1] is going to store the least significant byte but the opposite is happening: temp[0] is saving LSB and temp[1] is saving MSB. I already checked the I2C data with a logic analyzer but the sequence is the opposite of what my function prints.

Comment: What is the byte order of your compiler? Big endian or little endian?  Rather than cast two bytes to a uint16, write code to explicitly determine the byte order - eg: uint16_t val = byte[0] << 8 + byte[1];

Comment: @Kartman It is little endian.

Comment: "Obviously, temp[0] is supposed to store the most significant byte while temp[1] is going to store the least significant byte" - Why is this *obvious*? This is not how a little-endian machine works. The 'less significant' byte is stored in the memory with the lower address value. This is perfectly normal. Can you explain why it's a problem for you?

Comment: @brhans As far as I understand, it doesn't matter if my microcontroller is little-endian or not because inside the function 'leer_2_bytes_bmp180' I'm telling it to store the first byte in v[0] and the second one in v[1].

Comment: It does make a difference what endianess your cpu/compiler is.  Is your pointer value word aligned? Step through with a debugger or simulator to see what is really happening.

Comment: Which of the printf lines is giving you unexpected results?

Comment: @brhans the key here is that `recepcionI2C` is supposed to yield one byte at a time in the order they are sent by the sensor, which is MSB first.

Comment: @DamienD All of them. t[1] is printing 110 which comes first in the I2C sequence shown by the logic analyzer, t[0] is printing a value that is always changing and comes second and t is doing the operation with the bytes inverted.

Comment: Alternative hypothesis: the bytes aren't swapped, they're off by one and the first byte is garbage. Can you show your I2C code and the values of the register constants?

Comment: @DamienD I'm not at home now so I can't add my I2C code for now but here is this other post I opened in reddit where I show my I2C functions: https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/onqww5/why_is_my_i2c_function_inverting_bytes/

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is in your I2C code. Have a look here to double check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62906449

Comment: @DamienD I am going to move the STOP condition to see what happens.  Thanks.

Comment: I would bet on something like that. Some issue in the I2C flow that causes the read buffer to be swapped at the wrong time or one time too many.

Comment: @DamienD You were right. The bytes were not swapped and there was a problem with the I2C cycle.

Comment: Glad you could fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a problem with the STOP condition. In the datasheet it says that in case you want to read one single byte, you send the STOP condition before reading, but it doesn't explain what to do when you're reading more than one byte, and that's why I was sending the STOP after reading the last byte in this case.
So, apparently the sensor was sending an extra byte after every I2C cycle. This byte was not saved in a variable, but it was saved in the RXBUF register, and every time a new cycle started v[0] was assigned this value, while v[1] was assigned the byte wich was supposed to be the first one.This is the only function I needed to change

```
void leer_2_bytes_bmp180(uint8_t reg, uint8_t *v) {
    inicioI2C(DIR_I2C_BMP180);
    envioI2C(reg);
    reinicioI2C(DIR_I2C_BMP180, false);
    *v = recepcionI2C(false);
    *(v + 1) = recepcionI2C(true);        
}
```

I send a **true** value to *recepcionI2C* to indicate that this is the last byte which will be read and I removed *finI2C* because the STOP condition is sent in the last *recepcionI2C* call.

Answer (score 2):

Can't see any obvious flaw. I would try a read_uint16() function that uses a different idiom to compare the results:

```
uint16_t val = read_byte();
val <<= 8;
val |= read_byte();
```

Also advise using `0x%x` as a printf format to debug byte order issues.